# Azure web app write and read files

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have made a simple Java web app that runs on tomcat to explore azure environment.

I can read files (deployed via FTP to web app's root) from the web app, in a path denoted by HOME environment variable (azure's own env variable, resolves to `D:\home`):

```
String home = env.getProperty("HOME");

FileInputStream fis;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(home + "/" + "input.txt");

    //...

    fis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //...
}
```

But I can't write files to the same path:

```
String home = env.getProperty("HOME");
File file = new File(home + "/output.txt");

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

    //...

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) { //ACCESS DENIED
    return "ERROR :" + e.getMessage();
}
```

above code fails with access denied error.

Can I write persistent files to some path in azure, or do I need a cloud native storage for this?

Comment: I don't recommend saving files to local storage on Azure; my understating is that they may move your app to another instance, and they will only include the original package you uploaded when deploying the app.

Comment: @MokhtarAshour - Azure Web Apps provides *durable* storage which stays with your app, unless you completely delete it. This is not the same as a scratch disk in a VM.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create files directly under `%HOME%`, but you can created directories. And in there, you can create files. It's only files at the very root that it disallowed.